# Solargraph + Docker unable to bind to a different interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I'm using [solargraph](https://github.com/castwide/solargraph) server within a docker container. When the solargraph server is started with:

```
solargraph server
```

The server automatically binds to the 127.0.0.1 interface. This interface isn't accessible outside the docker container and prevents my IDE running on my host from talking to solargraph and getting the details it needs for autocompletion.

Does anyone know if it is possible to force the solargraph server to bind to a different interface? I seem to be able to change the port (with -p), just not the interface.

Output from solargraph:

```
root@ec55f4209be3:/app# solargraph server
[2018-09-18 12:00:25] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2018-09-18 12:00:25] INFO  ruby 2.3.5 (2017-09-14) [x86_64-linux]
== Sinatra (v1.4.8) has taken the stage on 7657 for development with backup 
from WEBrick
[2018-09-18 12:00:25] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=49 port=7657
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Sep/2018:12:01:16 UTC] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 512
```

Currently can access it only from inside the container by doing:

```
wget http://localhost:7657
```

**Update:**

I recently discovered one of my libraries was holding back installing the latest version of solargraph. I updated to the latest version which comes with a host option when running the server.

example:

```
solargraph socket --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5001
```

While this should work I still cant access solargraph server application.

Comment: Since I posted this, I have spoken to the solar graph owner and they have added ability to have solar graph listen on and external port to be able to connect visual studio code and solargraph in a container together. https://github.com/castwide/vscode-solargraph/issues/26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full definition of the publish flag for docker run actually [includes the hostname](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) . E.g.

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080/tcp ubuntu bash
```

Comment: I had in my docker-compose file 0.0.0.0:7657:7657/tcp. The problem is not so much docker itself but that the solargraph application always binds to 127.0.0.1. The command you provided and my compose line as I understand it tells docker where to bind the container to the host. But in this situation I need to change where the application is binding that is running inside the container.

Comment: Your suggestion did cause me to investigate the docker options further. one option is to run the docker container in host mode. I think that would work, but host doesn't seem to work under Windows or OSX and is a bit of a work around TBH.